# How can I replace string with another string in a gzip file by using python?

Tags: python, html

I am trying to find the specific string in gzip, replace it with another string and update the gzip file.

Here is my python script.

```
import gzip
import string

lines = gzip.open("PhoneWindowManager.java.gz", "rb")
definition = "name="+'"setHdmiPlugged"'+"/>"
print definition   
for line in lines:    
    if definition in line:
        before = ">"+"setHdmiPlugged"+"</a>"
        print before
        after = " title="+'"Join"'+"><font color="+'"red"'">"+"setHdmiPlugged"+"</font></a>"
        print after
        new_str = string.replace(line, before, after)
        print new_str
        **** How can I update the gzip file with the new_str? ****
        break
```

How can I replace the specific string and write it?

Actually I want to update the html tag of method definition with hyperlink title and red color

Before

```
<a class="l" name="5132" href="#5132">5132</a>    <b>void</b> <a class="xmt" name="setHdmiPlugged"/><a href="/source/s?refs=setHdmiPlugged&amp;project=android" class="xmt">setHdmiPlugged</a>(<b>boolean</b> <a class="xa" name="plugged"/><a href="/source/s?refs=plugged&amp;project=android" class="xa">plugged</a>) {
```

After

```
<a class="l" name="5132" href="#5132">5132</a>    <b>void</b> <a class="xmt" name="setHdmiPlugged"/><a href="/source/s?refs=setHdmiPlugged&amp;project=android" class="xmt" title="Test"><font color="red">setHdmiPlugged</font></a>(<b>boolean</b> <a class="xa" name="plugged"/><a href="/source/s?refs=plugged&amp;project=android" class="xa">plugged</a>) {
```

**EDIT**

I completed this code. Please refer to the below code if you needed.

```
import gzip
import string
import os

os.rename("PhoneWindowManager.java.gz","PhoneWindowManager_orig.java.gz")
input = gzip.open("PhoneWindowManager_orig.java.gz", "rb")
output = gzip.open("PhoneWindowManager.java.gz", "wb")
definition = "name="+'"setHdmiPlugged"'+"/>"

for line in input:    
    if definition in line:            
        before = ">"+"setHdmiPlugged"+"</a>"        
        after = " title="+'"Join"'+"><font color="+'"red"'">"+"setHdmiPlugged"+"</font></a>"
        new_str = string.replace(line, before, after)
        output.write(new_str)
    else:     
        output.write(line)

input.close()
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to replace a *specific string*:

```
a = 'string 1'
b = 'string 2'
a = a.replace(a,b)
```

When you print `a` the output is:

```
string 2
```